# Оборот "а во-вторых"

Tags: пунктуация

Насколько я знаю, "а" запятой не отделяется, но Ворд всегда подчеркивает пунктуационную ошибку в обороте "в во-вторых" (в-третьих и т.д.). Нужна ли тут запятая, или Ворд ошибается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, Ворд просто не может определить дифференцированные пунктограммы, встречается ведь и с запятой после А в других случаях.

Comment: Вы и меня успокоили, а то я тоже уже начала думать, что что-то не так пишу))))

Comment: Ну да, мы же считаем,что здесь всё должно учитываться, но это не так - только то, что заложат.Заложить дифференцированные написания и пунктограммы, чтобы учесть все оттенки мысли,невозможно, учитываются главные.

Answer (score 0):

Не выделяется. У Роженталя четко написано.

А ворд ошибается часто. Например, он всегда после млн и млрд требует ставить точку.